# enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions is not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

In which situation enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions is used.For running the code for every object of nsdictionary or nsarray we can also use "for in "loop construct then what is the use of this method.Any way if i use this on nsdictionary for going through every object it is altering the output .May be some thread concept is being applied. can anybody explain the reason.

here is a simple code what i used.

```
 NSDictionary *dict=@{@"1":@"india",
                         @"2":@"uk",
                         @"3":@"dubai",
                         @"4":@"china"
                         };

[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

    NSLog(@"key is %@",key);
     NSLog(@"value is %@",obj);

  }];
```

output:
] key is 3

key is 1

value is dubai

key is 4

value is china

value is india

key is 2

value is uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a for-in loop, you get each key in the dictionary. If you also want the value corresponding to that key, you then have to look it up in the dictionary in a separate step. That means (a bit) more code, and more code is always an opportunity for more bugs. Also, it restricts how efficient the enumeration can be. It will always require at least a message send per key-value pair.

With `-enumerateKeysAndObjects...`, you get both the key and value delivered to your block. You don't have to write the code to fetch the value using the key. Less code, less opportunity for error. Also, the design of the interface provides at least the *opportunity* for the implementation to be more efficient. Whether any given implementation actually is more efficient than the corresponding for-in loop is an open question. However, even if it's not currently, Apple can improve that with any release of the OS and apps which use `-enumerateKeysAndObjects...` automatically benefit without needing to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

As the apple docs says that

`NSEnumerationConcurrent`

```
Specifies that the Block enumeration should be concurrent. The order
of invocation is nondeterministic and undefined; this flag is a hint and
may be ignored by the implementation under some circumstances; 
the code of the Block must be safe against concurrent invocation.
```

and they also said

```
This option is available for NSArray and NSIndexSet classes; 
its behavior is undefined for NSDictionary and NSSet classes, 
or when combined with the NSEnumerationConcurrent flag.
```

it only says that the execution order of this is `nondeterministic` and `undefined` so it will execute concurrently so if u want to use `enumeratation` block use `- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key,id obj,BOOL *stop))block`

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"1":@"india",
                      @"2":@"uk",
                     @"3":@"dubai",
                     @"4":@"china"
                     };
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    NSLog(@"key is %@",key);
    NSLog(@"value is %@",obj);

}];
```

the out put will be like below

```
key is 3
value is dubai

key is 1 
value is india

key is 4
value is china

key is 2
value is uk
```

as u see for for `NSDictionary` and `NSSet` order of execution is different but u can get exact key value pair in this method.

for more info [Block enumeration operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/NSEnumerationOptions.)  in this see 
`NSEnumerationOptions`

Comment: ok i understood.  what is the use of enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock when compared to for in loop.and i want to process element by element in nsdictionay what is the procedure.

Comment: process the elements in the block, within the block u will get an object and its key, what else u need, for dictionaries process randomly you will get unique object and its key at each time, and it is not like array , `besides can u get ordered elements in for in loop for dictionary .. ?`

Comment: :just contsider NSarray then what is the differen between enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock and for in loop

Comment: But if i do like NSArray *keys =  [[resultdictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

       
        int i=0;
        for (;i<[resultdictionary count];i++)
        {
          NSString *country =[keys objectAtIndex:i];;
            NSString *beer = [resultdictionary objectForKey:country];;    } i am getting nsdictionary element by element .

Comment: in block also u can get element by element but order is different, what is really is it will make easy, what is the use of it, even though u can get each element element by sorting the keys u can get each element as u said for assay `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` you will get ordered values of the array along with its index and for dictionaries instead of index u get key and object

Comment: and also note that NSDictionary class represents an unordered collection of objects and  NSArray are ordered collection of object

Comment: Thanks. you and  Mr Ken Thomases has given me excellent answers

Comment: can i give two votes one for you and other for Mr Ken?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the NSEnumerationConcurrent option does, but you should try using enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: instead. It will output alternating keys and values. The keys will not be in any particular order, but that is to be expected for a dictionary.

Comment: if i use enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock also giving altered out put what is the reason?

Comment: @murali, what do you mean by "altered output"?

Comment: i mean it has to display like key is 1,value is india then key is 2 , value is uk, key is 3,value is dubai,key is 4 value is china. But it is displaying like key is 3,value is dubai,then key is 1,value is india,then key is 4,value is value is china,key is 2,value is uk.

Comment: @murali, as I said in my answer, that is to be expected. An NSDictionary is an unordered collection. You can't rely on the order of the keys, they're random.

Comment: ok i understood. means there is no mistake from enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock. what is the use of enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock when compared to for in loop.and i want to process element by element in nsdictionay what is the procedure.